# Get element of fomula from function call in R

Tags: r

I have defined a method for a class containing a `matrix` like:

```
setMethod(
    f = "test",
    signature = "MatrixSet",
    definition = function(object, ..., test, nme, subset, verbose = TRUE) {
          dta = object@matrix
          ## some changes in dta
          mod <- glm(..., data = dta)

          ## here I need to take the argument "formula" from "..."
          mod0 <- update(mod, as.formula(paste0(". ~ . - ", all.vars(formula)[1])))
          effect <- c(mod$coef[2], suppressMessages(confint(mod)[2,]))
          p <- anova(mod, mod0, test = test)
          p2 <- p[[nme]][2]

          return(list(effect=effect, p=p2))
    }
)
```

So, to take the `formula` argument from `...` I tried:

```
arg <- as.lsit(match.call())
```

But the content of `arg` shows me:

```
> arg
[[1]]
.local

$object
object

$formula
..1

$family
..2

$test
[1] "F"

$nme
[1] "Pr(>F)"
```

So... how I get the *real* content of `$formula` from `arg`?

I'm calling the function like:

```
test(dtaContained, formula=flu~PFHxS+age+sex, 
    family = gaussian, test = "F", nme = "Pr(>F)")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is related with the nesting environments between the R environment and class environment.

A possible solution is:

```
arg <- match.call(test, sys.call(sys.parent()), expand.dots=FALSE)
```

So the content of `arg` is:

```
> arg
test(object = dtaContained, ... = pairlist(formula = flu ~ PFHxS + age + 
    sex, family = gaussian, test = "F", nme = "Pr(>F)"))
```

Hence I get the formula from:

```
> as.list(arg)$...$formula
flu ~ PFHxS + age + sex
```

I am open to any answer that can improve this way or to complement it with more details.